# No registra datos en la BD MySQL desde un formulario

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

He conseguido mostrar los datos de mi BD en una tabla, pero a la hora de registrar nuevos datos desde un formulario simplemente no los crea, y no se donde está el error (Soy nuevo en php)

**insertar.php**

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Guardar datos</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$conexion = mysql_connect("mi_host" , "mi_usuario" , "mi_contraseña");

mysql_select_db("nombre_DB",$conexion);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (numero,fecha,cliente,direccion,telefono,averia,estado,observaciones) VALUES ('numero','fecha','cliente','direccion','telefono','averia','estado','observaciones')";

 mysql_query($sql);

?>
</body>

</html>
```

**formulario.php**

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Guardar datos en una base de datos</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" action="insertar.php">

    <p>Numero de Aviso <input type="number" name="numero" size="20"></p>
    <p>Fecha <input type="date" name="fecha" size="20"></p>
    <p>Cliente <input type="text" name="cliente" size="20"></p>
    <p>Direccion <input type="text" name="direccion" size="20"></p>
    <p>Telefono <input type="number" name="telefono" size="20"></p>
    <p>Averia <input type="text" name="averia" size="20"></p>
    <p>Estado <input type="text" name="estado" size="20"></p>
    <p>Observaciones <input type="text" name="observaciones" size="20"></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Guardar datos" name="B1"></p>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Revisa la versión de PHP que tienes en tu servidor, ya que _mysql_connect_ es obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. 
Recomiendo cambies a [mysqli] (http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Veo la variable $sql y no veo cuando le das los datos para insertar, por lo general concatenas dentro de esa cadena los datos que le vas a pasar y ademas revisa la versión de tu servidor pues esa forma de conectarse a base de datos esta obsoleta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciertamente me había faltado un detallito men, y de una vez te lo coloqué con Mysqli. Lo probé y me funcionó:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Guardar datos</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$conexion =new mysqli("servidor","usuario","contraseña","base_de_datos");
 
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}

/* TE FALTABA ESTABLECER LAS VARIABLES CUYA INFORMACIÓN RECIBES POR EL MÉTODO "POST" Y SE HACE DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA: */

$numero = $_POST['numero']; 
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$averia = $_POST['averia'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$observaciones = $_POST['observaciones'];

/* LUEGO LAS INSERTAS EN ESTA LÍNEA COMO LO TENÍAS, PERO LOS VALUES LLEVAN $ YA QUE SON LAS VARIABLES ESTABLECIDAD ARRIBA, TAL COMO TE LO MUESTRO: */

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (numero,fecha,cliente,direccion,telefono,averia,estado,observaciones) VALUES ('$numero','$fecha','$cliente','$direccion','$telefono','$averia','$estado','$observaciones')";

mysql_query($sql,$conexion);

/* ESTO TE LO HE ANEXADO PARA QE TE EMITA UN MENSAJE Y VER SI SE GUARDARON O NO LOS DATOS (PODRÍAS MEJORAR SU ESTÉTICA CON UN POCO DE JAVASCRIPT Y) */
if ($sql>0)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert ('Los datos se guardaron exitosamente');
window.location='pagina_donde_iras_luego_de_guardar.php';
</script>";
}
else
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert ('Error al guardar');
window.location='pagina_donde_iras_si_falla_el_guardado.php'; /* TE RECOMIENDO QUE LO REGRESES AL LLENADO DEL FORMULARIO (Elimina este comentario antes de usar el código) */
</script>";
}
?>
</body>
```

Como dice el amigo en el comentario de abajo, el HTML en estos casos sólo se usa si deseas mostrar algo, en mi caso te lo coloqué así porque te recomendé la librería **SweetAlert**

Comment: Lo he puesto exactamente como me lo has puesto poniendo mis datos de acceso (host, usuario, pass y tabla), cambiando mysql_connect por mysqli_connect etc... y cambiando la página de salida. Y al probar el formulario me da error. No encuentro donde tengo el fallo

Comment: Me sigue dando error, esta vez no me salta el alert de error, me tira directamente a la página insertar.php (la pagina que estamos programando) en blanco

Comment: Entonces el error debe estar en tu servidor tal como han comentado bro porque yo hice la prueba en Localhost y me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

> En los procesos como **insertar.php** no debe tener html a excepción
>   si quieres mostrar algo

```html
<?php
$conexion = mysql_connect("mi_host" , "mi_usuario" , "mi_contraseña");

mysql_select_db("nombre_DB",$conexion);

//preguntamos si recibimos el boton guardar datos
if(isset($_POST['B1'])){
//generamos las variables recibidas por POST que es equivalente al name del input
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$averia = $_POST['averia'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$observaciones = $_POST['observaciones'];
//luego teniendo los datos podemos validar campos si son distintos de nulos o darle reglas de negocio.
//si la dirección no esta vacía y que observaciones tenga mas de 3 caracteres
if($direccion != '' && strlen($observaciones)> 3){
//ahora procedemos a guardar
//Si el numero es AI(auto incrementable) no es necesario insertarlo.
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (fecha,cliente,direccion,telefono,averia,estado,observaciones) VALUES ('".$fecha."','".$cliente."','".$direccion."','".$telefono."','".$averia."','".$estado."','".$observaciones."')";

 mysql_query($sql);
}
//para terminar un header para volver a la vista
header("Location: destino.php");
}
```